# Bellman Ford randomly producing wrong results

Tags: java, algorithm, bellman-ford

I'm trying to implement the Bellman Ford Algorithm from CLRS, and it randomly seems to overflow on the distance metric. My code is as follows:

```
private void initSingleSource(Vertice source) {
    for(Vertice vertice:vertices) {
        vertice.distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        vertice.predecessor = null;
    }
    source.distance = 0;
}

private void relax(Vertice u, Vertice v, int weight) {
    if(v.distance > u.distance + weight) {
        v.distance = u.distance + weight;
        v.predecessor = u;
    }
}

public boolean bellmanFord(Vertice source) {
    initSingleSource(source);
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size()-1; i++) {
        for(Vertice u: edges.keySet()) {
            Hashtable<Vertice, Integer> table = edges.get(u);
            for(Vertice v: table.keySet()) {
                 relax(u, v, table.get(v));
            }
        }
    }
    for(Vertice u: edges.keySet()) {
        Hashtable<Vertice, Integer> table = edges.get(u);
        for(Vertice v: table.keySet()) {
             if(v.distance > u.distance + table.get(v)) {
                 return false;
             }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Input for the code is:

```
g.addAdjList(A, B, 6);
g.addAdjList(A, D, 7);
g.addAdjList(B, C, 5);
g.addAdjList(B, D, 8);
g.addAdjList(B, E, -4);
g.addAdjList(C, B, -2);
g.addAdjList(D, C, -3);
g.addAdjList(D, E, 9);
g.addAdjList(E, C, 7);
g.addAdjList(E, A, 2);
```

The correct answer, which I randomly get is:

> B 2 C 4 D 7 E -2

Otherwise I get:

> B -2147483636 C -2147483634 D -2147483631 E -2147483640

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Hint: table.keySet() may not produce the same order for different runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem arises when `relax` is called with `u` such that `u.distance` equlas `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Then `u.distance + weight` is negative (the sum goes out of bounds). That negative value is smaller than `v.distance` and gets assigned to `v.distance`.

That may happen or not, depending on the order of `relax` calls. The order is random, as you use `table.keySet()`. If you have the luck to consider vertices in the order that DFS would do, you should get correct results, but that is not likely.

**Possible solution**

```
private void relax(Vertice u, Vertice v, int weight) {
    if(u.distance != Integer.MAX_VALUE && v.distance > u.distance + weight) {
        v.distance = u.distance + weight;
        v.predecessor = u;
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like a good solution. But now it got me wondering, should I even iterate over the edges using `keySet()`? Seems like a bad way to introduce non deterministic bugs. What's the preferred data structure/iteration method for cases like this?

Comment: I don't think `keySet()` is bad. It makes sure that your algorithm does not depend on the order of vertices. If it was not random, you could have a test case which would run fine despite the bug and not discover it.